# Which method in BMP is used to avoid unnecessary round trips to the database?

Tags: ejb-3.0

If I'm using BMP bean, is there any method which avoids unnecessary roundtrips to database and increase the efficiency...

Does any of these method serve the purpose? (Question in a certification test)
ejbSave(), ejbStore() or ejbPersist()

In a multi-tiered architecture, with database, application server, and Web layers—you optimize performance by reducing the network traffic “round trip.”  Best approach is said to be to start and stop transactions at the application server level, in the EJB container. So would like to know the methods help reduce unnecessary round-trips for that in Bean Managed persistence type beans....Am new to ejb.., so am trying to learn the concepts

ejbSave() and ejbpersist() do not exist...

Comment: have added some context..would this suffice...

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't have to deal with any of these methods: 'ejbSave(), ejbStore() or ejbPersist()'

> If I'm using BMP bean, is there any method which avoids unnecessary roundtrips to database

## Short Answer:

Yes, methods of [EntityManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html)

## Long Answer:

To avoid network round trips to the database, you'd just have to set the transaction boundaries correctly. When you use the methods provided by EntityManager (I'm talking about JPA), the methods act on the persistence context. The persistence context being a cache, real db hits are avoided until the commit happens.

---

Following is a section from the [TomEE docs](http://openejb.apache.org/jpa-concepts.html)

> ## JPA 101
>
> If there's one thing you have to understand to successfully use JPA (Java
>   Persistence API) it's the concept of a *Cache*.  Almost everything boils
>   down to the Cache at one point or another.  Unfortunately the Cache is an
>   internal thing and not exposed via the JPA API classes, so it not easy to
>   touch or feel from a coding perspective.
>
> Here's a quick cheat sheet of the JPA world:
>
> - A *Cache* is a *copy of data*, copy meaning pulled from but living
>     outside the database.
>
>   - *Flushing* a Cache is the act of putting modified data back into the
>       database.
>   - A *PersistenceContext* is essentially a Cache. It also tends to have
>       it's own non-shared database connection.
>   - An *EntityManager* represents a PersistenceContext (and therefore a
>       Cache)
>   - An *EntityManagerFactory* creates an EntityManager (and therefore a
>       PersistenceContext/Cache)
>   - With  *you* are
>       responsible for EntityManager (PersistenceContext/Cache) creating and
>       tracking...
>       -- You *must* use the *EntityManagerFactory* to get an EntityManager
>       -- The resulting *EntityManager* instance *is* a
>       PersistenceContext/Cache
>       -- An *EntityManagerFactory* can be injected via the *@PersistenceUnit*
>       annotation only (not @PersistenceContext)
>       -- You are *not* allowed to use @PersistenceContext to refer to a unit
>       of type RESOURCE_LOCAL
>       -- You *must* use the *EntityTransaction* API to begin/commit around
>       *every* call to your EntityManger
>       -- Calling entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager() twice results in
>       *two* separate EntityManager instances and therefor *two* separate
>       PersistenceContexts/Caches.
>       -- It is *almost never* a good idea to have more than one *instance* of
>       an EntityManager in use (don't create a second one unless you've destroyed
>       the first)
>   - With  the *container*
>       will do EntityManager (PersistenceContext/Cache) creating and tracking...
>       -- You *cannot* use the *EntityManagerFactory* to get an EntityManager
>       -- You can only get an *EntityManager* supplied by the *container*
>       -- An *EntityManager* can be injected via the *@PersistenceContext*
>       annotation only (not @PersistenceUnit)
>       -- You are *not* allowed to use @PersistenceUnit to refer to a unit of
>       type TRANSACTION
>       -- The *EntityManager* given by the container is a *reference* to the
>       PersistenceContext/Cache associated with a JTA Transaction.
>       -- If no JTA transaction is in progress, the EntityManager *cannot be
>       used* because there is no PersistenceContext/Cache.
>       -- Everyone with an EntityManager reference to the *same unit* in the
>       *same transaction* will automatically have a reference to the *same
>       PersistenceContext/Cache*
>       -- The PersistenceContext/Cache is *flushed* and cleared at JTA
>       *commit* time

> ## Cache == PersistenceContext
>
> The concept of a database cache is an extremely important concept to be
>   aware of.  Without a copy of the data in memory (i.e. a cache) when you
>   call account.getBalance() the persistence provider would have to go read
>   the value from the database.  Calling account.getBalance() several times
>   would cause several trips to the database.  This would obviously be a big
>   waste of resources.  The other side of having a cache is that when you call
>   account.setBalance(5000) it also doesn't hit the database (usually).  When
>   the cache is "flushed" the data in it is sent to the database via as many
>   SQL updates, inserts and deletes as are required.  That is the basics of
>   java persistence of any kind all wrapped in a nutshell.  If you can
>   understand that, you're good to go in nearly any persistence technology
>   java has to offer.
>
> Complications can arise when there is more than one
>   PersistenceContext/Cache relating the same data in the same transaction. 
>   In any given transaction you want exactly one PersistenceContext/Cache for
>   a given set of data.  Using a TRANSACTION unit with an EntityManager
>   created by the container will always guarantee that this is the case.  With
>   a RESOURCE_LOCAL unit and an EntityManagerFactory you should create and use
>   exactly one EntityManager instance in your transaction to ensure there is
>   only one active PersistenceContext/Cache for the given set of data active
>   against the current transaction.